# Preventing axis being messed up by adding new objects to the scene in Front Perspective View

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, interface

I've already had question according [array modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1534/array-modifier-y-and-z-reversed). I had changed object alignment from 'Align To: World' to 'Align To: View' in the 'User Preferences'. It's because i wanted to add objects in 'Front Persp' and spare me rotation steps i every time take when i'm adding a new object. After changing it i ended up having problems with modifiers relative offset properties, i had to tweak the 'Y' axis to move it up and 'Z' axis property to move it in the direction where normally 'Y' axis would be. So the question is: **is it possible to add objects in 'front ortho' without messing up the axis of the object?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you either get it aligned to your current view, including the object's local orientation, or globally oriented.

### [Apply object rotation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Reset_Object_Transformations#Apply_Object_transformations)

Go to Object Mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> *(Apply Rotation)* and your object orientation is applied, meaning that the mesh stays exactly the same but all 3 axes are parallel to the global ones afterwards.

### Concerning default behaviour

You can't make blender apply the rotation of your object all the time or always when you add an object.

I guess it would be possible to write a python addon/macro to always realign the axes for you after adding an object, but someone else would have to help you with that.

### Other workaround

You can add any object first from top view (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>), delete the mesh (<kbd>X</kbd>) and re-add the mesh you want from the perspective you want (e.g. front with <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>). This will only add the mesh within the already correctly aligned object. Which is not really a lot faster than the method mentioned above, sadly.

### Third (probably best) workaround

Go to top view (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>), add the object, go to front view (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>), press <kbd>F6</kbd>, (disable and)* re-enable "align to view", this re-aligns the mesh to the current view without altering the object orientation.

- only if align to view is enabled by default

Comment: Great!! it does work but could short explain why? Did i just rotated objects orientation to have it aligned with global orientation? because the object itself does seem to stay untouched.

Comment: and is it possible to set it as default behavior?

Comment: It basically rotates the objects to be aligned to the global coordinates, and then rotates the mesh back to where it was before from a global point of view, so both the orientation of the object and the position of every point within the object change, but globally, the mesh stays where it was.
-- 
See also: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Fade/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Reset_Object_Transformations
 -- 
I added a comment on the default possibilites above, but there is no ideal solution.

Comment: I added a third workaround that's probably even better, partially based on sambler's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The option to align to view or world is available to each object added. Pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> after adding an object gives you the operator options, which is also visible at the bottom of the tool palette by default. Among the options you have for a newly added object is Align to view, if turned off it is aligned to world.

[image]